# Allign different column names during concant in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes

`df1`

```
created_at      centre          product_id          qty         sale_value      many_more_columns
2021-05-24      london          aa                  10          5.00            ...
2021-05-24      paris           bb                  5           5.00            ...
2021-05-24      paris           aa                  7           5.00            ...
2021-05-24      rome            cc                  6           5.00            ...
```

`df2`

```
day_id          prod_id     branch_name         order_id    sales           many_more_columns   
2018-01-30      ab          paris               4           976.00          ...
2018-02-06      ds          london              1           5.00            ...
2018-07-20      gf          oslo                1           49.00           ...
2018-09-30      aa          rome                2           3.00            ...
2019-01-14      bb          rome                3           25.00           ...
```

I am trying to contact these dataframes so that these columns sit below each other

- created_at - day_id
- centre - branch_name
- product_id - prod_id
- qty - order_id
- sale_value - sales

The rest of the columns are different, I would like to fill those with `np.nan` value.

So that the result would look like this:

```
created_at      centre          product_id          qty         sale_value      many_more_columns
2021-05-24      london          aa                  10          5.00            ...
2021-05-24      paris           bb                  5           5.00            ...
2021-05-24      paris           aa                  7           5.00            ...
2021-05-24      rome            cc                  6           5.00            ...

2018-01-30      paris           ab                  4           976.00          np.nan
2018-02-06      london          ds                  1           5.00            np.nan
2018-07-20      oslo            gf                  1           49.00           np.nan
2018-09-30      rome            aa                  2           3.00            np.nan
2019-01-14      rome            bb                  3           25.00           np.nan
```

After using `pd.concat([df1, df2])` I get `df2` shifted to the right which is expected. Is there a way to tell pandas that one column is the same as another in other dataframe? I could think of renaming `df2` columns to match `df1`, but want to know if there is a way to achieve this with `pd.concat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
d={'day_id': 'created_at',
 'branch_name': 'centre',
 'prod_id': 'product_id',
 'order_id': 'qty',
 'sales': 'sale_value'}
```

Finally:

```
out=pd.concat([df1,df2.rename(columns=d)])
```

**OR**

```
out=df1.append(df2.rename(columns=d))
```

Comment: That works, just you needed to swap `d` keys and values places.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis yup...I noticed and corrected it....Kindly have a look on answer again ***:)***

Comment: Thanks, so I understand that `pc.concat` does not have intermediate colunm matching, so renaming them before hand is the way to go?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis yup because if you are concat 2 or more df's on axis 0(which is by default)  that have different columns then concat will create seperate columns for each unique columns in the list of df's `[df1,df2,....]`  but If you have  the same column name in 2 or more df's then it will concat it to single row